# Django admin login_redirect url next parameter

Tags: django

I need a user to be redirected to a different page(for two factor authentication) once he logins inside the admin page.

I tried to populate the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL and it does not work.

As per the document.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

the default page is '/accounts/profile/' if the next parameter is not given.

How can I pass the next parameter, do I need to change the login_page html to include the next parameter?

Comment: Where does it redirect after login?

you can use /?next={{redirect_path}}

and LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL has been deprecated since django 1.8

Comment: It logins to the admin page once I give the username/password.

Comment: did you created a custom login page?

Comment: no, Im using the existing admin page.

Comment: I think you will have to create your custom login page.

Comment: ok, fine..Thanks.